# How do I map an Oracle timestamp to a DateTime in Fluent NHibernate?

Tags: c#, oracle, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have a column in Oracle that is a TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE.  I am getting an exception when attempting to load records from the table:  **System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException : Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime.**

Here is what I have tried for the mappings:

```
Map(x => x.ExpirationDate, "EXPIRE_DATE").CustomType("timestamp").CustomSqlType("TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE").Nullable();

Map(x => x.ExpirationDate, "EXPIRE_DATE").CustomSqlType("TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE").Nullable();

Map(x => x.ExpirationDate, "EXPIRE_DATE").CustomSqlType("timestamp").Nullable();

Map(x => x.ExpirationDate, "EXPIRE_DATE").CustomType("timestamp").CustomSqlType("timestamp").Nullable();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using an Oracle function inside the SQL in order to get a date time out.  See the EXPIRE_DATE below:

```
string sql = @"SELECT CONTAINER_ID,
PLANT_ID,
MATERIAL_ID,
QTY_IN,
QTY_OUT,
UNIT_OF_MEASURE,
TO_CHAR (EXPIRE_DATE, 'YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS MY_EXPIRE_DATE,
LOT_ID,
CONTAINER_STATUS,
CONTENTS_TYPE
FROM POMSNET.MM_CONTAINER_ST
WHERE CONTENTS_TYPE = 'Raw Material'
AND QTY_IN - QTY_OUT > 0";
```